# Update value in array and store updated array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to update an array value and submit the array with a new function. However, the array is not updating correctly, do I miss something?

Array data:

```
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        [item] => Array
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [description] => Value 1
                    [amount] => 6.00
                    [status] => 1
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [description] => Value 2
                    [amount] => 1.00
                    [status] => 1
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [description] => Value 3
                    [amount] => 4.00
                    [status] => 0
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

PHP code:

```
        foreach($array->$item as $key => $value)
        {
            $data[$key]['description'] = preg_replace('/\bValue\b/i','UpdatedValue',$data[$key]['description']);
        }

        // Pass update to new array
        $params = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'description' => array($array->item->description),
            'amount' => array($array->item->amount),
            'status' => array($array->item->status),
        );
```

Comment: Where is the array `$data` declared and involved in the update?

Comment: This: `$array->$item` isn't array syntax. Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: `foreach($array['items']['item'] as $key => $value)` then there are others issues inside the loop.  Turn on error reporting to see.

Comment: Could you give us an example of what `$params` is supposed to look like, this may require a lot more information as there a quite a few errors with this. Until we know what your trying to do helping is going to be hard.

Comment: ```$params``` is supposed to look like:

```array(
            'id' => $id,
            'description' => array(originalkey => value, anotherkey => value),
            ...
        );```